# Convert a Cell of Strings to a Double in Matlab

Tags: matlab, double, cell

How do i convert a Cell as the following:

```
>> A = [{'2'};{'2'};{'****'};{'23'};{'23.6'}]

A = 

    '2'
    '2'
    '****'
    '23'
    '23.6'
```

To a double as the Following

```
A =

    2.0000
    2.0000
       NaN
   23.0000
   23.6000
```

Answer (score 4):

[`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) can be called directly on a cell array of strings:

```
>> X = str2double(A)
X =
    2.0000
    2.0000
       NaN
   23.0000
   23.6000
```

---

On an unrelated note, the notation used to define the cell array `A` can be simplified a bit:

```
>> A = {'2'; '2'; '****'; '23'; '23.6'}
A = 
    '2'
    '2'
    '****'
    '23'
    '23.6'
```

no need for all those curly brackets :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `str2double` on each entry of the cell array like this:

```
cellfun(@str2double, A)
```